# Why is this gen_statem call blocking?

Tags: erlang, fsm

Hello i am trying to figure out when using the `gen_statem` why do the calls block,since my fsm is running in a separate process.

```
-module(fsm).
-record(data,{
    current="None",
    intvCount=0,
    jobCount=0
}).
-export([init/1,terminate/3,callback_mode/0,code_change/4]).

-export([state/1,start/0,interview/2,reject/2,wait/1]).

-export([sitting_home/3,interviewing/3]).
-export([handle_event/3]).
-behaviour(gen_statem).

handle_event({call,From},get_state,Data)->
    io:format("why you need state>"),
    {keep_state,Data};
handle_event({call,From},Event,Data)->
    {keep,state,Data}.
%API
start()->
    gen_statem:start_link(?MODULE,[],[]).
state(PID)->
    gen_statem:call(PID,get_state).

interview(PID,Company)->
    gen_statem:call(PID,{intv,Company}).
reject(PID,Company)->
    gen_statem:call(PID,{reject,Company}).
wait(PID)->
    gen_statem:call(PID,{wait}).

%mandatory
code_change(V,State,Data,Extra)->{ok,State,Data}.
callback_mode() ->
    state_functions.
init([])->
    {ok,sitting_home,#data{current="None",jobCount=0,intvCount=0}}.
terminate(Reasom,State,Data)->
    void.

% State implementations

sitting_home({call,From},{intv,Company},Data=#data{intvCount=C})->
    io:format("called for interview"),
    {next_state,interviewing,Data#data{intvCount=C+1},{reply,From,something}};
sitting_home({call,From},Event,Data)->
    {keep_state,Data}.

interviewing({call,From},{rejected,Company},Data)->
    {next_state,sitting_home,Data,{reply,From,somethingelse}};
interviewing({call,From},wait,Data)->
    {keep_state,Data}.
```

**Usage**:

```
>{ok,Pid}=fsm:start().
>fsm:state(). //blocks !

>{ok,Pid}=fsm:start().
>fsm:interview(Pid).
 called for interview %and blocks
```

Why do both calls block? I am spawning a different process besides the shell in which the `fsm` runs using the `gen_statem:start_link`.
Why in both cases it blocks?

**Update**
I have updated my post after i was pointed out that i forgot to use `reply` in order to send something back to the caller.However the `handle_event/3` still blocks even in this form:

```
handle_event({call,From},get_state,Data)->
    {keep_state,Data,[{reply,From,Data}]}.
```

Comment: Recheck what you have done (compile, module load ???), @Alexey answer is correct.

Comment: I just always `c(name of module)`

Comment: Well, I checked on my PC to verify, by replacing the last line `{keep_state,Data}.` of `sitting_home/3` function with `{keep_state,Data,[{reply,From,sitting_home}]}.` the function `fsm:state(Pid)` doesn't block anymore.

Comment: The problem was that i thought you can handle events with custom methods that don't need to  pass through your state methods.In my case i thought `handle_event\3` could be called directly when the `state` event fired .Instead it would get on the `sitting_home` branch that did not have any `reply` for the caller thus it was blocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's what `gen_statem:call` does:

> Makes a **synchronous** call to the gen_statem ServerRef by sending a request **and waiting until its reply arrives**

and your state functions don't send any replies. They should look like

```
sitting_home({call,From},{intv,Company},Data=#data{intvCount=C})->
    io:format("called for interview"), 
    {next_state,interviewing,Data#data{intvCount=C+1},{reply,From,WhateverReplyYouWant}};
```

or

```
sitting_home({call,From},{intv,Company},Data=#data{intvCount=C})->
    io:format("called for interview"), 
    gen_statem:reply(From, WhateverReplyYouWant),
    {next_state,interviewing,Data#data{intvCount=C+1}};
```

If there's no useful reply, consider

1. using `cast` instead of `call` (and handling `cast` as the `EventType` in your state functions), or
2. `ok` as the reply.

Comment: I have used the `reply` in the state methods and also in my `handle_event/3` and it is still blocking.

Comment: `handle_event` isn't used because of your callback mode (and should be `handle_event/4` for `handle_event_function`). So `fsm:state()` call is handled by the `sitting_home({call,From},Event,Data)->...` branch which still doesn't reply anything.

Comment: But `interview()` should stop blocking and return `something`; have you recompiled the module?

Comment: Wait, your `interview` should have 2 arguments, not 1.

Comment: I have added `reply` to all state methods and yes i am recompiling the module every time.

Comment: I have not used the `interview` event at all.The code blocks when i require the `state`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204368/discussion-between-bercovici-adrian-and-alexey-romanov).